# Calculating time for a biker to coast down a hill

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

**A biker has traveled $79$ m up a hill inclined at $33.0^{\circ}$. At some point, the rider stops and coasts back down the hill. How much time does it take to make it back to the bottom of the hill?**

This question is really confusing me as I keep getting the wrong answer.

So this is what I keep doing:

**First assumption I make:** I only need the vertical (y) height of the hill because the time spent should only be dependent on horizontal motion

From there I do:    $$ y (\text{height}) = 79\sin(33) = 42.02648 \approx 42.027 m $$

So from there, I assume I can use the equation: $$ x = v_ot + (1/2)at^2$$
$$42.027 = 0 + (1/2)(9.81)t^2 $$

But when I solve for $t$, I get $$ t=2.927$$

Which apparently is wrong.

P.S: **I really hate online University, I hope it ends soon.**

Comment: The acceleration down the hill is not g but gsin(theta) and the distance is the length of the incline and not the vert. height.

Comment: You forgot to consider the de-acceleration caused by the normal reaction in the vertical direction. So your net acceleration would be $g-\frac{N\cos\theta}{m}$ in the vertical direction. Though having this approach won't help you in this problem.

Comment: Hello there, and welcome to the Physics Stack Exchange! Homework and "check my work" questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. Please read [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) on asking homework questions and [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) for "check my work" questions.

Comment: @VincentThacker    I appreciate the feedback but I think this was a pretty specific example plus I showed my work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did.
The force down the incline is $mg \ sin\theta$. 
The acceleration down the incline would be $g \ sin\theta = 5.343 \ \text{ms}^{-2}$ in this case.

I applied $s = ut +\frac{a t^2}{2}$ and got the answer as $5.438 \ \text{s}$

Comment: Wait how did you get the final answer? Even if I use the new acceleration value I then have the equation:  $$ 42.027 = 0 + (1/2)(5.343)t^2 $$ which results in t = 3.99

Comment: take the distance down the incline (79m), not the perpendicular distance.

Comment: Oh. Interesting.  When you throw an object off a cliff, you use the vertical component  to determine how long it spends in the air.  I wonder why you use the hypotenuse in this case

Comment: Here the normal reaction offered by the incline is also acting on the body. I just used the set of axes where we could ignore that component. You always choose the simplest axes for analysis. Here it turns out to be along the incline.